# How can i create a User control of my asp.net web solution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, wcf-client

I have asp.net Web Solution with WCF services. How do I convert the solution to a User control so that I can use it in my other applications uniformly.

Actually I want to convert my application to a user control.what is the easiest way of doing it. its an ASP.Net application.

Thanks in advance
IRP

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is not possible nor should it be desired.
If you pack your WCF service into a control what if there is more than one control on a page? What with the different user-sessions?

And of course this is strongly against the *Seperation of Concerns*-Principle.

What I would do is write a small framework, where one part is the Service and one part is the user-control. Basically you copy and past all you need into a new library-project and maybe do the ABC-stuff in code if you don't like the web.config aproach.